# Problems connecting to db using Zend db as standalone

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am migrating from ZF1 Zend_db to ZF2. I have problems connecting to the db and making a simple query. Appreciate if someone can guide me along. Below is my code.

This is how i connect to db

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
$dbo = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'database' => DB_PREFIX.DB_NAME,
    'username' => DB_USER,
    'password' => DB_PW
));
Zend_Registry::set('db', $dbo);
```

This isan example how i use it.

```
$this->dbo = Zend_Registry::get('db');

function createData($message,$tags,$userid,$imgsrc){
    $data= array(
                      'message' => $message,
                      'tags' => $tags,
                      'imgsrc' => $imgsrc,
                      'createdtimestamp'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
                      'userid' => $userid);   
    $this->dbo->insert('mydata', $data);
    return $this->dbo->lastInsertId();
}
```

I have an error. That is $dbo does not have select(),insert() methods etc. I could did it in ZF1 zend db.

Example of error message i received:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::select() in

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that ZF2 and ZF1 are (and should be) class-compatible. The problem is, they're not - at least in regards to `Zend\Db\Adapter`. That one in ZF2 is much more concise: while it has `query` method, its main responsibility is abstracting the DB connection itself.

I suppose what you're looking for is located in [**Zend\Db\Sql**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html) area. Assuming you have your DB connection in `$dbo`, you can create an Sql object based on it:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql as Sql;
$sql = new Sql\Sql($dbo);
```

... then create another object (of `Zend\Db\Sql\Insert` class):

```
$insert = $sql->insert('mydata');
$insert->values([
   'message' => $message,
   'tags' => $tags,
   'imgsrc' => $imgsrc,
   'createdtimestamp'=>new Sql\Expression('NOW()'),
   'userid' => $userid
]);
```

... then use this object in query:

```
$insertString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert);
$results = $dbo->query($insertString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```